# Hadoop Sqoop export to Teradata Error

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, teradata, sqoop

I'm trying to export the data to TERADATA using Sqoop. The entire mapreduce.Job gets completed however the data is not loaded and it shows the following.

```
15/07/08 01:27:36 INFO processor.TeradataOutputProcessor: input postprocessor
com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataBatchInsertProcessor starts at:  1436333256770
15/07/08 01:27:36 INFO processor.TeradataBatchInsertProcessor: insert from staget table to target table
15/07/08 01:27:36 INFO processor.TeradataBatchInsertProcessor: the insert select sql starts at: 1436333256969
```

What's wrong?

I used the following script to load

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:teradata://172.XX.XX.XX/Database=PRD_XXX_XXX \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
--username GDW_XYV  \
--password 123 \
--export-dir /user/xxxx/xxx_xxx/2001/ \
--table PRD_XXX_XXX.TABLE_T_HD \
--input-fields-terminated-by '|' \
--input-escaped-by '\\' \
--input-enclosed-by '\"' \
--input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"' \
--mapreduce-job-name sq_exp_xxx_xxx_2001 \
--verbose \
-m 20
```

Comment: During Sqoop Export 
Teradata creates a temp table by same structure as target table for eg: let target table name be sales_edw the TD will create a temp table sales_edw_1029XXX. Sqoop Load the data to temp. Once completed the data is copied back to main table and the temp table is dropped

Comment: Did you manage to overcome this issue?

Answer (score -1):

As Max said, it is taking **split.by.partition** where it is creating a temporary stage table. You can force the stage table creation in another database where you have access, or you can use **split.by.value**, **split.by.hash** or **split.by.amp**

**Note:** **Split.by.hash** also creates a partitioned staging table if your input table is not partitioned. However if your input table is partitioned, no extra stage table is created.